# Makefile target inside conditional

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel

Sorry if this is a simple question, but most resources I've been able to find for Makefile tutorials cover only the extreme basics.

I'm attempting to interpret a Makefile that has a target inside a conditional ifneq. Additionally, said target is never declared as .PHONY but is called "all default". See below:

```
ifneq ($(SOME_VARIABLE)$(ANOTHER_VARIABLE,)
    all default: check_a check_b 
        $(MAKE) ARCH=somearch CROSS_COMPILE=archcompiler -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
else 
    obj-m += ...
endif
```

This is a simplified version, but hopefully gets the point across. My question is essentially:

> Why isn't 'all default' declared as .PHONY? Is definitely isn't making a file called 'all default'.
>
> Does a Makefile execute top-to-bottom like normal code? How could you even execute anything above a target?

This Makefile is building a linux kernel (or just kernel modules?), which I'm guessing is why I'm so confused. Can anyone recommend resources to help me begin to understand how all of this works? I don't even know where to start.

Comment: I have found very few "tutorials" on the internets that I would recommend for people trying to understand makefiles.  My recommendation is to read the GNU make manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html  At the very least, reading the introductory chapters should give you a better concrete understanding than reading random tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't defining a rule to build a target called `all default`.

It's defining two rules to build two different targets, one called `all` and one called `default`.  Multiple targets separated by spaces in an explicit rule define that same rule for each target.

Also note, that declaring a target `.PHONY` is not mandatory.  Usually make will work the same way regardless of whether or not the target is explicitly marked `.PHONY`.

Marking a target `.PHONY` has these benefits: it's slightly more efficient (but hardly noticeable), and *if* you happen to create some file or directory with the same name as your target then it will continue to work.

In other words, as long as you don't create a file or directory named `all` or `default`, then your makefile will work properly even if these targets are not declared `.PHONY`.

As for your second question: no, makefiles are not processed procedurally, like programs or shell scripts.

The way it works is that make parses all the makefiles, included makefiles, etc. first and constructs an internal graph of all the targets and their prerequisites.  Then after that's done, it chooses a starting node in the graph (either ones you asked for on the command line or else the first one in the makefile) and starts to walk the graph, building things that are out of date.